# One Image in EMail doesnt show using Nodemailer and an HTML Template

Tags: html, html-email, nodemailer

I am using Nodemailer to send E-Mails.
Nearly everything works just fine.
The E-Mail I send is a template that I generated with: https://beefree.io/

The Problem:
One of the four images doesn't show up.

In the End of the E-Mail there are 3 Images for Social Media: Facebook, G+ & Twitter. They show.
On the top half there is another picture, which is larger (300kb), it doesn't show.

When I open the E-Mail with Microsoft Edge for example all images that show up have an img src like:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg [....] uQmCC">
```

But the image that doenst show up still has src:

```
src="./images/email.png"
```

Folder Structure

```
-- templates  
---- images  
-------- email.png  
-------- facebook.png  
-------- googleplus.png  
-------- twitter.png  
---- emailtemplate.html
```

My path in the html template are:

```
src="./images/facebook.png"
src="./images/twitter.png"
src="./images/googleplus.png"
src="./images/email.png"
```

The email.png image is a free stock photo, that I converted from .jpg to .png using Paints "Save as".

I dont know anything about static or dynamic links...

Thanks for your help.

This is what the E-Mail looks like:
[image: Image not showing (backup Text: image)]

This is what happens when I change the "email.png" to "facebook.png":
[image: Facebook image would show up)]